# How do I get the between of the dates in my listbox for each line?

Tags: c#, date, combobox, listbox, average

I am trying to make an application that can add dates for hotel rooms and get the average time between the dates. I have made 2 calendars, 1 for the starting date and the other one for the ending date. When I show the output in the listbox, I don't know how to get the days between this dates. I need them to calculate the average.

I've tried to get the dates but I'm confused with the datetime things.

```
lbDates.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", cmbBoxRoom.SelectedItem, tbBooking.Text, calArrival.SelectedDate, calDeparture.SelectedDate));
```

How can I get the between of the dates so I can calculate with that?

Comment: you need to get all dates between Start and End Date. right.?!

Comment: Just how long is between those dates

Comment: `var deltaTime = calDeparture.SelectedDate.Subtract(calArrival.SelectedDate)` delaTime is a TimeSpan of the amount of time in between these two dates

Comment: @RemcoBisschops `var td = (dtEndDate - dtStartDate).TotalDays;` gives total days between two dates

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below code

```
            DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Start Date: " +Convert.ToString(a));

            DateTime b = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).AddHours(5);
            //b = b.ToUniversalTime();
            Console.WriteLine("End Date: " +Convert.ToString(b));

            TimeSpan result = b - a;

            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(result));
```

Two variable a & b takes values for start and end date.
Result wil show the output difference between both in Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Check below link

https://rextester.com/PZQ26216

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply want to get the time between two dates. In C# this is trivially easy using the `DateTime.Subract()` method like so:

```cs
TimeSpan deltaTime = calDeparture.SelectedDate.Subtract(calArrival.SelectedDate);
```

or you can use the plain old `-` operator

```cs
Timespan deltaTime = calDeparture.SelectedDate - calArrival.SelectedDate;
```

This is the same as using the `Subtract` Method

The `deltaTime` time variable is a TimeSpan holding the amount of time in between the two dates, you can now (for example) do `deltaTime.Days` to get the amount of days in between the two dates